# How can I show that $x^4+6$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I show that the polynomial $x^4 + 6$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ without explicitly finding factors?

I was trying to find a non-prime ideal that would generate it but I'm kind of lost as to how to proceed. Is there some sort of criterion that will allow me to show that it's reducible in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Let $a$ be positive. Thn $x^4+a=(x^2-kx+\sqrt{a})(x^2+kx+\sqrt{a})$ where $k=\sqrt{2\sqrt{a}}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

Then use the fact that if a complex number $z$ is a root of a *real* polynomial, then $\bar z$ is also a root.

It follows that in $\Bbb R$ only the polynomials of degree one, and the quadratic polynomials with negative discriminants are the irreducible.

Comment: Wouldn't the fundamental theorem only allow me to show that the polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Danny yes. But every complex number is a root of a polinomial of degree two. Therefore, you can split it up into two polinomials of degree two.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a theorem that shows that every complex number is a root of a polynomial of degree two?

Comment: If $x=a+bi$ then $(x-a)^2=-b^2$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what does z-bar represent?

Comment: @Danny the complex conjugate: if $z=a+ib$ then $\bar{z}=a-ib$

Comment: @CBenni thanks!